# how to structure @Query selects where @Param is an object

Tags: java, eclipselink, spring-data

I am using Spring data / Eclipse link in an application.  I understand how to build a simple query as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT l FROM Location l WHERE l.street = :street")
public Location findByLocation(@Param("street") String street);
```

What I am confused about is how to build a more complex query of the form.  The following causes compilation errors:

```
@Query("SELECT l FROM Location l WHERE l.street = :location.street AND l.city=location.city")
public Location findByLocation(@Param("location") Location location);
```

I guess this is really query by example?  I know that I could use eclipse link directly to build the query (although I am not sure how to acquire the Spring managed entity manager) but this seems to break the approach of using pure Spring.

Comment: Why don't you pass in the location.street and location.city values directly instead of the location entity, as I don't think Spring knows enough to pull out just those values for your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have finally addressed this is as follows (thanks to Chris's comment):

```
@Query("SELECT l FROM Location l "WHERE (l.street IS NULL OR l.street = :street) AND (l.city IS NULL OR l.city= :city) ")
public Location findByLocation(@Param("street") String street, @Param("city") City city);
```

The requirement for the "IS NULL" is to allow for matching when either city or street is not set.